# SSL Certificate Not getting passed

Tags: java, spring, ssl, jboss, spring-integration

I have configured the SSL configuration for my jboss.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/appserver/jboss5.1/test.jks   
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=********* 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/appserver/jboss5.1/test.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*******
```

I am using the spring integration to connect to restservice, the ssl certificate is getting passed for some request and it is not getting passed for some other request, Any idea why the certificate will not be passed for one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the servers responsibility to request the client to send a certificate during mutual authentication.

When you have time, verify that the server has the ssl 'clientAuth' attribute set 'true' for all the urls that you want mutual authentication (client authentication).

Comment: I may not have followed it fully, I am invoking a secure (https) rest client using RestTemplate inside Jboss. You mean to say I have explicitly pass the certificate as part of rest client invocation?

Comment: That is not what I am saying.  The server that your RestTemplate is calling (the remote server), is what determines if your client is required to send an authentication certificate or not.  What I am asking you to do, if possible, verify that all the urls that you're calling on the remote server require mutual authentication (meaning that clientAuth for a tomcat ssl connection is set to want or true).  If you cannot verify the remote server's settings, you can watch the ssl handshake by starting your app with the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl option.

Comment: Thanks, we identified the problem, it was a different application on same app server setting the SSL System property to different one.